# How to plot users' country information on a JavaScript Map as 'Pins' of data points against each country? Geocoding stuff

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, openlayers

This is a simple 'how-to' question.

I have users in my database with their country name. I want get this country information of all the users and show it on a JavaScript Map as 'Pins' of data points. Like, for example, if I have users from Brazil, there will be a Pin on Brazil, etc.

What is the best method to do this, since I'm only looking at countries? I just saw [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) but I'm not sure it is the answer. Displaying a tooltip with total number of users within that country, onhover, would be a big plus.

Answer (score 0):

A sample script to create the pins on the map is as below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
    var myOptions = {
       zoom: 4,
       center: myLatlng,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);    
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: myLatlng, 
       map: map,
       title:"This is Australia!"
     });   
 }
```

1. You will need to get the Lat, Lng of the center point of each country
2. You have various options to get the data to javascript
       i. if you are using asp.net MVC, you could create an action that returns JsonResult
      ii. you could use ajax to make a call to a server method and get the results.
3. Finally, manipulate the data in javascript by looping through the list to create the marker pins.

Comment: do you have a running example of this? i mean, i did get what you said, but, do not know which js files to include and stuff.

Comment: i guess this is it http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html

Comment: Yes, that is one example, you can find loads more examples for the Google maps api usage here - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html. If you have any specific questions regarding the usage, let me know and I'll try to provide examples.

Comment: thanks for that link. as you said, I'll need Lat and Lng for the mid-point of every country. I figured I can use Google's geocoding api for this. But, there are many Lat, Lng points when I query http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=India&sensor=false for example. The returned json string contains many such points. how to get the mid-point out of these values?

Comment: i mean, if you look at the JSON output, is it the 'lat, lng' within 'location', inside 'geometry'?

Comment: Yes, the latlng within location should give you the centre point.